# Recent change in jQuery attr return type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm confronted by a strange jQuery problem.

I was asked to help figure out why a site broke recently. They are loading the latest version of jQuery from a CDN, and making liberal use of it, including features like `attr`. I have very little experience with jQuery; I've heard `attr` is broken, and I've seen that it performs poorly, so I never use it.

Anyway, this code has things like `foo = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]` all over the place, and all of that broke recently. Apparently, `attr` used to return a String, and now it returns a jQuery object. It's simple enough to go through and change code like this to a somewhat more sensible `foo = this.className.split(' ')[0]`, but I wonder if I'm going about this the wrong way.

So, my question is: Is there a jQuery configuration setting to get `attr` to act like it did in the previous version, and return a String? If not, has anyone else run into this problem? How did you handle it?

Comment: [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) still returns a string ..

Comment: Mmmm...works fine for me with latest jquery 1.7.2 here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/MRCNt/

Comment: FYI, referring to the first class name is generally a bad thing to do also so even `foo = this.className.split(' ')[0]` is asking for trouble.  Class names have no guaranteed order if any code starts adding and removing them.  Using jQuery, `hasClass()` is the right way to detect if a particular class is present.

Comment: The entire code is terrible. You guys are right, I have no idea how or why the `attr` in this code is returning jQuery objects... this should probably just be closed as too localized. I don't think I'm going to bother to mess with this project anyway.

Comment: Somehow removing these calls to `attr` and replacing them with POJS equivalents is making things work. And rolling back to the previous version of jQuery fixes everything. Something is going on here, but I'm not sure what yet. I'll just leave this here for a while until I figure it out.

Comment: if `this` is just a single element (like `this` in a `.each()` operation), then you can do `this.className` to get the classes.

Comment: @Joseph it's like thousands of lines of code with this all over the place, I'm having to fix it up with clever find / sed commands... that's why I'm not really trying the fix the positional class name problem. This code has way worse issues.

Comment: jQuery's native `.attr()` now, as always, returns a string. If anything other than a string is returned then some plugin must be overriding the native method. This would drive any experienced jQuery programmer nuts.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot imagine how it makes someone who doesn't like using GP libraries in the first place feel. It took me an hour to figure out why $ was defined half the time and half the time not. It seems someone threw some noConflicts in there just for flavor. I don't think anyone was looking at the console much either. And yeah, they are doing some kind of plugin-like stuff, assuming that's what modifying properties of jQuery.fn is about.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot but still, this code-like stuff was somehow working before the jQuery update... and i looked at this in my console and saw attr returning a jQuery object with my own eyes in the new version, and a string in the old version. Also, the `var` keyword is nowhere in sight, everything is leaked into the global scope, and every variable is named with a leading $, so i wonder if something is just conflicting with jQuery internals somehow. Who knows. By the way, I voted to close =p

Comment: Sounds like the code has gown like topsy over a stretch of time and with multiple, uncoordinated programmers. Pretty well a nightmare scenario. Can only offer sympathy @GGG.

Comment: It's been handled a lot. I think I'm just going to suggest freezing it and only doing (sorely needed) critical security updates.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Remember to add a note in the "documentation" to that effect.

Comment: Any added notes would pretty much be the extent of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer (along with this is probably not the best way to do this *thanks @GGG) is that this seems to be related to the way JQuery refactored .prop() to take make .attr() behave better in version 1.6. Without going BACK to previous versions, you cannot ask JQuery to change its behavior.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/prop/